# Why can't HorizontalGauge be directly added to the control part of Manipulate[]?

Tags: manipulate, gui-construction

I try to use `HorizontalGauge` in `Manipulate` as follows:

```
    Manipulate[
 Graphics[Disk[]],
 HorizontalGauge[Dynamic[x], {0, 100}]
 ]
```

but it didn't work. If I wrap the gauge with `Row[]`, then it works. Can anyone explain why it works like this?

```
    Manipulate[
 Graphics[Disk[]],
 Row@{HorizontalGauge[Dynamic[x], {0, 100}]}
 ]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In [`Manipulate >> Details and Options`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Manipulate.html) allowed forms of the second argument are listed:

[image]

So  `HorizontalGauge[Dynamic[x], {0,10}]` (or, for that matter, `Slider[Dynamic[x], {0, 10}]` or `Checkbox[Dynamic[z]]` or `InputField[Dynamic[w]]` etc.) is not allowed in the second (or later) argument.

The highlighted row of the list is elaborated on as

[image]

So using `Row @ {HorizontalGauge[...]`, `Style @ HorizontalGauge[...]`, `Text @ HorizontalGauge[...]` etc. do work.

Comment: Okay, thank you.